# add text to a path by adding text to it with python (FTP Path NCBI)

Tags: python

I'm in a bind please. do you know if i can duplicate the last folder in the path please and add "_genomic.fna.gz" to it for example how to change from this

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3
```

to this :

```
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3_genomic.fna.gz
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib.parse.urlparse` can split your URL into parts we can work with.
`posixpath.join` can help us build the full path.
`urllib.parse.urlunparse` can help us get a complete URL back.

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> import posixpath
>>> url = "ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3"
>>> parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
>>> parts.path
'/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3'
>>> posixpath.basename(parts.path)
'GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3'
>>> suffix = "_genomic.fna.gz"
>>> prefix = posixpath.basename(parts.path)
>>> print(prefix+suffix)
GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3_genomic.fna.gz
>>> path = posixpath.join(parts.path, prefix+suffix)
>>> path
'/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3_genomic.fna.gz'
>>> ret = parts._replace(path=path)
>>> print(urllib.parse.urlunparse(ret))
ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/001/316/945/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3/GCA_001316945.3_ASM131694v3_genomic.fna.gz
>>>
```

Comment: import wget
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd    URL='https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/refseq/bacteria/assembly_summary.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(wget.download(URL) , sep = '\t', header = 0)

species = input("bacteria species? : ")   

if data["organism_name"].str.contains(species, case = False).any():

 print(data.loc[data["organism_name"].str.contains(species, case = False)]['assembly_level'].value_counts())    
 FTP_list = data.loc[data["organism_name"].str.contains(species, case = False)]["ftp_path"].values
 else:    
    print("this species not found")

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I'd like to put you a bit on topic so you understand better. here is the code I want to add this option to in the comment above. if you could take a look please. I have put a dataframe file with pandas, and from the user input of the species choice, I would like to get the Path URLs and modify them as I explain. or by adding after the ftp_path: +"/"+ assembly accession (in the table) and then add "_" then asm_name.
this for each line, i.e. for a given line: its ftp_path with its asm_name and its assembly accession.

Comment: "I'd like to put you a bit on topic" -  LOL, *you* are being off-topic. I answered your question above. If you cannot use my answer in your dataframe then you need to post a new question, preferably a [mre].

Comment: I did not say it was not possible; in fact, it's not hard. I said you need to post a *new* question with a sample of your DataFrame. Again, preferably a [mre].